# How to evaluate $\int_{-\infty}^t v(\alpha)\,d\alpha$ for $v(\alpha) = \sin\alpha$?

Tags: integration

Integral form of the inductor's V-I relation is:

$$i(t) = \frac{1}{L} \cdot \int_{-\infty}^t v(\alpha)\,d\alpha$$

How can I determine this function for 
$v(\alpha) = \sin\alpha$? I've tried to but I don't know what to do with infinity.

Comment: It doesn't converge classically in this case...

Comment: When you try plugging $-\infty$ in the antiderivative, it won't exist since $\sin$ is oscillatory.

Comment: The integral $\int_{-\infty}^t \sin \alpha d\alpha $ does not exist, hence your expression for $i(t)$ is undefined.